# C++ Type Traits: enable_if -- can this be simplified?

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits

This is kind of ugly. Is this the simplest, most readable way to write this in C++17, or can it be cleaned up further?

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, bool> = true>
T increment(T v) {
    ...
}
```

The best I can think of is to add this to an include file:

```
template <typename T>
using IsArithmetic = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, bool>;
```

And then use it like this:

```
template <typename T, IsArithmetic<T> = true>
T increment(T v) {
    ...
}
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Instead of `bool = true` I recommend `std::nullptr_t = nullptr` to prevent the possibility of multiple instantiations by manually passing the arguments. Otherwise looks good to me, I don't think it can be shortened further without macros.

Comment: @Joseph - Your best simplification is basically the best C++17 can do. Even standard library implementations employ it or a version of it. Given they are written by the most knowledgeable of experts, I don't think we can do better.

Comment: Using SFINAE in the return type might look better: `template <typename T> std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, T> increment(T v) {/*..*/}`

Comment: I think I have already seen `REQUIRES` MACRO. not sure if it does something in C++17 though :/

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, wouldn't it be better to `enable_if` on the return type? That way you can never override it...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, As far as I understand, this does still allow you to overload just based on SFINAE (because the SFINAE basically handles the overload resolution before actual overloading - although I know that you know much more on this than I do). Here's an example though: https://godbolt.org/z/19GhbzPx6  Although I agree that it doesn't work on constructors, or class specialisation (no return types!), but I thought it was a good idea to use it when it's available.

Comment: @Elliott Sorry, my bad. I confused it with `typename = enable_if_t<...>` style, which fails for those overloads. Then the only remaining reason to not SFINAE on return type is it not working in constructors.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of specifically defining `IsArithmetic`, you can define a type alias named `Requires`

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... Cond>
using Requires = std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<Cond...>, bool>;
```

Then use it like

```
template <typename T, Requires<std::is_arithmetic<T>> = true>
T increment(T v) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, interesting. Not necessarily shorter, but it's a more generic solution that works with any predicate and isn't specific to is_arithmetic.

Comment: This trick is also common in [implementations of libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/9385cd9c74cf6662f43038aafe4d2467899f322e/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/optional#L742).